# WPF: How to bind data from a code behind variable to content in xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I cant bind the variable from code behind in my wpf radiobutton

Can anyone help me to display the values from the variables in the content from the radio button.

MainWindow.xaml:

```
            <RadioButton GroupName="Preis" Grid.Row="10"  Content="{Binding Name1}" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
            <RadioButton GroupName="Preis" Grid.Row="11" Content="{Binding Name2}" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
            <RadioButton GroupName="Preis" Grid.Row="12" Content="{Binding Name3}" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
            <RadioButton GroupName="Preis" Grid.Row="13" Content="{Binding Name4}" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
            <RadioButton GroupName="Preis" Grid.Row="14" Content="{Binding Name5}" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Produkte produkte = new Produkte();
        produkte.Name1 = "Handstaubsauger";
        produkte.Name2 = "Fensterwascher";
        produkte.Name3 = "Dampfreiniger";
        produkte.Name4 = "Hochdruckreiniger";
        produkte.Name5 = "Geschenkgutschein";

        // Regex für Email
        String regexEmail = @"^(?("")("".+?(?<!\\)""@)|(([0-9a-z]((\.(?!\.))|[-!#\$%&'\*\+/=\?\^`\{\}\|~\w])*)(?<=[0-9a-z])@))(?(\[)(\[(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}\])|(([0-9a-z][-\w]*[0-9a-z]*\.)+[a-z0-9][\-a-z0-9]{0,22}[a-z0-9]))$";

        // Hier weitermachen

    }

}
```

Produkte.cs

```
public class Produkte
{
    public String Name1 { get; set; }
    public String Name2 { get; set; }
    public String Name3 { get; set; }
    public String Name4 { get; set; }
    public String Name5 { get; set; }
    public Int16 Stimmen1;
    public Int16 Stimmen2;
    public Int16 Stimmen3;
    public Int16 Stimmen4;
    public Int16 Stimmen5;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Produkte produkte = new Produkte();
    produkte.Name1 = "Handstaubsauger";
    produkte.Name2 = "Fensterwascher";
    produkte.Name3 = "Dampfreiniger";
    produkte.Name4 = "Hochdruckreiniger";
    produkte.Name5 = "Geschenkgutschein";


    //  ADD THIS
    DataContext = produkte;


    // Regex für Email
    String regexEmail = @"^(?("")("".+?(?<!\\)""@)|(([0-9a-z]((\.(?!\.))|[-!#\$%&'\*\+/=\?\^`\{\}\|~\w])*)(?<=[0-9a-z])@))(?(\[)(\[(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}\])|(([0-9a-z][-\w]*[0-9a-z]*\.)+[a-z0-9][\-a-z0-9]{0,22}[a-z0-9]))$";

    // Hier weitermachen
}
```

Note that if you try to bind to `Stimmen1`, `Stimmen2`, etc. in your view, it will fail, because they are fields. They must have `{ get; }` to be able to bind to them.

You really need to turn `Produkte` into a proper viewmodel with `INotifyPropertyChanged` etc., but this will get a read-only view working right now.

Answer (score -2):

In your xaml within the Window tag on the top, you would need to define your `DataContext`. If it is your code behind it would be `Self`. Once you have the `DataContext` set, you will be able to access public properties for binding.

```
<Window x:Class="Account.Client.PotentialMisallocation.Controls.DisplayAndFilter"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
```

You will need to expose a public property of type Product in your code behind:

```
    public Product Product
    {
        get { return new Product() {Id = 1, Name = "James"}; }
    }
```

Then in xaml, you would do sth like:

```
 <Label x:Name="label" Content="{Binding Product.Id}" />
 <Label x:Name="label1" Content="{Binding Product.Name}" />
```

Comment: How do i have to adjust the content in the xaml? It still does not show the text.

Comment: Did I suggest sth wrong? Downvoter, could you drop a comment please?

Comment: Why are you telling him to set DataContext to self? That's totally unnecessary, and it gets to be a terribly bad habit. They do it with UserControls and it causes no end of frustration. Assign the *viewmodel* to the DataContext. That's what the DataContext is for. I would guess with a high degree of confidence that that was behind the dv.

Comment: OP specifically asked referring to code behind though. I do understand the  concept of MVVM, but the OP seems to be unaware and may be doesn't even need for his scenario. Anyway, thanks for clarifying.

Comment: If OP was asking this question, he doesn't know that he's asking a slightly wrong question, or more accurately thinking about the right question in a slightly wrong way. He doesn't have a well-informed reason to do it wrong. He's just asking how to make it so he can see the strings on the screen.

Comment: And even if it *were* right not to use a viewmodel, *you still don't set DataContext to `this`*. You use `{RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}` or whatever in the bindings. Setting DataContext to this is actually, seriously, a bad idea, and totally unnecessary under any circumstances.

Comment: Could you link me to some articles that explain why this is a bad idea or elaborate where it comes to hurt? I genuinely intend to learn more because I tend not to care for MVVM for simple scenarios and use this approach and haven't had any issues. Considering your SO rep and your conviction in that statement, I feel that I may be missing some info and want to fill that knowledge gap that's why I asked...

Comment: The biggest problem is in UserControls. You set DataContext = this, and then the bindings *on* the user control's own external properties all fail because you stepped on the DataContext they should be using. We get questions about this from time to time. Also, a common use for UserControls is as a reusable view, in which case everything internally depends on inheriting the parent's DataContext. Finally, it simply creates confusion in a new WPFer's mind between view and viewmodel -- the last thing they need, with a learning curve like WPF's.